# Let a be a real number greater than 1 so that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-a}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^a} = (1-2^{1-a})\sum_1^\infty n^{-a}$ for a > 1

Please help me with this one.
My thoughts: I tried breaking down both sides and I was stuck. I guess I have to use the fact that a > 1 for simplification.

Comment: This is called the Dirichlet eta function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function

Answer (score 1):

Order the odd and the even terms in the first sum to break it into 2 sums.

Answer (score 0):

Working directly with the left side:

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^a}
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{(-1)^{(2n-1)-1}}{(2n-1)^a}+\frac{(-1)^{2n-1}}{(2n)^a})
\qquad\text{separate odd and even terms}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{(-1)^{2n-2}}{(2n-1)^a}+\frac{(-1)^{2n-1}}{(2n)^a})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{(2n-1)^a}-\frac{1}{(2n)^a})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{(2n-1)^a}+\frac{1}{(2n)^a}-\frac{1}{(2n)^a}-\frac{1}{(2n)^a})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{(2n-1)^a}+\frac{1}{(2n)^a}-\frac{2}{(2n)^a})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{(2n-1)^a}+\frac{1}{(2n)^a})-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{(2n)^a}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^a}-\frac1{2^{a-1}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^a}
\qquad\text{combine odd and even terms}\\
&=(1-\frac1{2^{a-1}})\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^a}\\
\end{array}
$